# Adding custom JavaScript file to footer.php

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to add something like this to a WordPress page: ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bCN6/))

```
var div = $('#move');
var upper = $('#up');
var downer = $('#down');

upper.click(function() {
    div.animate( { top: '-100'}, 500);
});
downer.click(function() {
    div.animate( { top: '0'}, 500);
});
```

I know how to add the divs and the CSS to get that all working correctly, but I can't seem to figure out how to add the JavaScript to make the two divs (up and down) to work correctly. I can't seem to find anything on adding that code to the footer as well. From what I understand, the only way to have functionality like that is to have the code in the footer.

I tried a few different solutions, but none of them seem to work.

The name of the file is java.js that I have the functions stored in

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>wp-content/themes/kallyas/js/java.js"></script>
```

I placed that in footer.php right after the closing body tag, but again didn't work.

I may have the path wrong. From the base of the wordpress install, I have it here: `wp-content/themes/kallyas/js/java.js`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the script loading from `header.php`, and also remove any jQuery loading from it. Then, you can use [**`wp_enqueue_script`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to make your JS file load at the footer and to force the inclusion of other files (jQuery in this case) as [dependencies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress).

Add to your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_so_18552010' );

function enqueue_so_18552010()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'my-java', // Handle
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/java.js', // URL for child or parent themes
        array( 'jquery' ), // Dependencies
        false, // Version
        true // In footer
    );
}
```

---

*PS: [**Don’t Dequeue WordPress’ jQuery**](http://eamann.com/tech/dont-dequeue-wordpress-jquery/%C3%A7) and if you do it, do it correctly with [**Use Google Libraries**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/use-google-libraries/).*

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your **functions.php** file:

```
//Ad our custom Jquery
function init_js_scripts() {
if (!is_admin()) {
    //Use Google to get JQuery libary...
    wp_register_script('jquery', ('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'), false, '');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    // load a JS file to your theme: js/theme.js
    wp_enqueue_script('my_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myjavascript.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

    }
}
add_action('init', 'init_js_scripts');
```